# how to write block with arg. "UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>" in Swift closure

Tags: objective-c, swift

please help with syntax:

```
__weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;
[self.audioFile getWaveformDataWithCompletionBlock:^(float **waveformData,
                                                     int length)
{
    [weakSelf.audioPlot updateBuffer:waveformData[0]
                      withBufferSize:length];
}];
```

The waveform data itself will be an array of float arrays, one for each channel, and the length indicates the total length of each float array.
 @param waveformData An array of float arrays, each representing a channel of audio data from the file
 @param length An int representing the length of each channel of float audio data

in swift I have:

```
cell.audioFile.getWaveformDataWithCompletionBlock { (UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>, Int32) -> Void 

}
```

I stuck on UnsafeMutablePointer>

I need to use this arg. in:

cell.audioWaveView.updateBuffer(buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer, withBufferSize: Int32)

Comment: Does `UnsafeMutablePointer<[Float]>` work?

Answer (score 1):

I know this may be an old question, but I was struggling with the same thing and I finally solved:

You need to pass the argument to the block as a WaveformDataCompletionBlock closure, and your parameters should be an UnsafeMutablePointer and a UInt32. So the code should be something like this:

```
self.audioFile = EZAudioFile(URL: self.soundFileURL)
var waveClosure: WaveformDataCompletionBlock = {
  (waveForData: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>, length: UInt32) in
  //Do something
}
self.audioFile.getWaveformDataWithCompletionBlock(waveClosure)
```

I hope this could be useful to somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @FelipeDev.- posted, this question is old but still helped me today (Thanks Felipe!). However, there is a slightly updated answer to this now with the newer versions of EZAudio and Swift. I got this to work with the following code:

```
var waveClosure: EZAudioWaveformDataCompletionBlock = {
        (waveformData: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>, length: Int32) in
        //Do something like update the audio plot buffer if you are plotting the waveform
        self.audioPlot.updateBuffer(waveformData[0], withBufferSize: UInt32(length))
    }
self.audioFile.getWaveformDataWithCompletionBlock(waveClosure)
```

Hope this helps!